# iptables rules to issue with tftp

Tags: iptables

My requirement is to add iptables rules in such a to allow tftp traffic(as a client) and drop everything else. And in fact using the iptc library programmatically using C code.
To start with I tried with command line, with the help of references following seems to work fine:

---

```
./iptables -I INPUT 2 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT
./iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT

./iptables  -I INPUT 3 -p udp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

./iptables -I INPUT 4 -j DROP
./iptables -I OUTPUT 3 -j DROP
```

---

My query is

1. Above unless I specify 'NEW' along with ESTABLISHED,RELATED tftp doesn't seemed to work fine. But in some of questions asked in this website I see mentioning  ESTABLISHED,RELATED are enough. What am I missing here? What is the main purpose of NEW and will it open gates for new issues?
2. Also for this rule how is the iptc library implementation? What extensions to add to the rule before committing?

   ```
   ./iptables  -I INPUT 3 -p udp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   ```

Comment: Use `-A` instead of `-I` together with some number, the latter is hell to maintain if you want to add some rules halfway: you have to renumber everything! Just use append, much simpler. Also for the `OUTPUT` rule use `-o eth0`, not `-i` (think about it...)